# How to increase font size of description in cventry for modern cv?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, moderncv, description

I was wondering how to increase the font size of the full description section in a cventry within moderncv. Here is the cventry I wish to use:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9, top=1cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\name{test}{test}

\begin{document}

\cventry{Date}{Job Description}{Company}{Location}{}{Full Description}

\end{document}
```

What I basically want to do edit the cventry so that for all entries the font size of the description is /normalsize without having to actually put  in \normalize like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9, top=1cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\name{test}{test}

\begin{document}

\cventry{Date}{Job Description}{Company}{Location}{}{\normalsize Full Description}

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot comparison:

[image]
[image]

I am using moderncv v1.3.0

Comment: Is it possible for you to update `moderncv`? The current version is 2.0, your version 1.3 is a little bit outdated ...  But I will see, if I can find this old version.  Give me a little bit time to search, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, with your old version 1.3 the command `\cventry` is defined as:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%  % <===================================
%                  ^^^^^            <===================================
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

The important part for you (I have marked with `<=======`) it the hard coded usage of `\small` before parameter `#7`.

I think the best way would be to define an new own command `\mycventry`. There we just leave out `\small` you do not want. Or you can add `\normalsize` as you did in your given code (okay, if you have not to write this too much; it compiles with version 1.3 fine as you can see in the following MWE and screenshot ...

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % version 1.3

\moderncvstyle{banking}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9, top=1cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}



\firstname{John} %Vorname
\familyname{Doe} % Nachname
%\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\cventry{Date}{Job Description}{Company}{Location}{}{Full Description}
\cventry{Date}{Job Description}{Company}{Location}{}{\normalsize Full Description}
\mycventry{Date}{Job Description}{Company}{Location}{}{Full Description}

\end{document}
```

You see the two calls of `\cventry` and the call of `\mycventry`? Compare please the result with the following pdf:

[image]

The two last calls have the wished normal size.

The advantage of defining an own command is that you can easy change the code of your own command, if the original command in class `\moderncv` has changed (for example there are a lot of renaimings in version 2.0).